# Custom item for Gridview not inflated properly

Tags: android, gridview, grid, android-custom-view, baseadapter

I have the following Gridview inside a fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_photos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the custom item made for the Gridview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    gra
    android:id="@+id/image_view_gallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the adapter's getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photos_grid_view, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_gallery);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }
    Glide.with(context) //
            .load(PhotosFragmentConstants.IMAGES[position])
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .crossFade()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);


     return imageView;
```

so the image should have a border because of the relative layout. The image has set layout margins so it creates a border effect, but it  doesn't work.
When i run the app,  you can see only the image view and there is not layout behind him.

Is there a way that i need to make the item for the gridview so it will display it properly? 
Thank you for the help!

Comment: can you please remove the code in the else section and then check...bcoz  your convert view is grid item which is relativlayout with image view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_photos_grid_view, null);
}

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_gallery);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

Inflate the layout if it is null, and after that find the views you need. You also might want to consider using a viewholder for performance reasons.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Yep i solved it a couple of minutes ago, the problem was that i was returining an image, not the converView. So I created a viewHolder with a image inside, and at the end i returned convertview not the image. *And i removed the else*